# jQuery .html() not inserting content

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery to dynamically insert content into a `div` with an id of "target". The jQuery is supposed to run when a link is clicked, but it isn't working. Why is this code not working?

HTML:

```
<div id="options" name="onclick-dropdown">
<p style="" id="discussion-opener"><a href="#" name="add-a-comment">Add a comment</a> or 
<a href="#" name="start-discussion" id="start-discussion">start a new discussion</a>.</p>
</div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#start-discussion").click(function(e){
  $("#target").html("<div class='dropdown'><textarea style='font-family:latine; text-align:justify; width:250px; height:400px;'></textarea></div>");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: according to this fiddle, your code seems to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/bkr4qc3u/

Comment: Your bug is not reproducible with your [given code](http://jsfiddle.net/tv7mru7u/).

Comment: [Here](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/discussion/discussion.php) is where the page is. It's not running on the page, though the fiddle works.

Comment: any console errors in your browser?

Comment: @Lal, I didn't get any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in the header, but not in a doc ready handler, so it cannot find the elements it is referencing (e.g. `$("#start-discussion")` does not match anything as that has not been loaded yet):

```
$(function(){

    $("#start-discussion").click(function(e){
      $("#target").html("<div class='dropdown'><textarea style='font-family:latine; text-align:justify; width:250px; height:400px;'></textarea></div>");
      e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Note: `$(function(){});` is a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Another option is to place your script inclusion at the end of the `body` element so you can also then guarantee the DOM is ready.

The final option is to have a delegated event handler, as the `document` element always exists and the selector is only used at event time.

```
$(document).on('click', '#start-discussion', function(){
      $("#target").html("<div class='dropdown'><textarea style='font-family:latine; text-align:justify; width:250px; height:400px;'></textarea></div>");
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

This one can still go in the `head` element, without a DOM ready handler, and still work. :)

Comment: So I should put the code in a `$(function(){   });`?

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided works as intended. I think your issue is that you are not waiting for the DOM to be ready in your jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#start-discussion").click(function (e) {
        $("#target").html("<div class='dropdown'><textarea style='font-family:latine; text-align:justify; width:250px; height:400px;'></textarea></div>");
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/93ers3o3/)

The document ready will insure your elements are within the DOM when you add the `eventHandler`. As you are using `ID` selectors this is required.

Comment: Ya, this is it! OP was calling snippet from HEAD section, while the element not available in the DOM so no event was bound

Comment: @A. Wolff: I don't think I have seen you this excited over a missing DOM ready handler before :)